# Magento2 missing Street Information instead of having validation

Tags: magento2, missing, street-address

Magento2 I am facing a strange issue where the customers are missing Street Information in the Shipping address. In the Shipping Address form I have added Street Field as required still shipping address is missing for some orders in admin.

Any suggestion how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

---

Did you get to the bottom of this one Arjun?

I see the same problem, small number of random orders coming in without 1st address line.